# MYSQL: Getting certain data from a cross join depending on condition

Tags: mysql

This is my problem query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      t.name AS tname, 
      t.task_group AS tg,
      tgs.name AS tgname
      FROM tasks AS t, task_users AS tu, task_groups AS tgs
      WHERE (tu.worker = 1 AND t.keyid = tu.task AND tgs.keyid = t.task_group);
```

The query works. The thing is that the part of the WHERE clause that does tgs.keyid = t.task_group filters out the results where this condition is not true (which is, of course correct).

How can I modify this query and still get tname when this condition is NOT true and in that case obtain a predefined string as tgname?

To give some extra information when this condition is not true t.task_group is allways -1. In this case I would like to get a tgname of "N/A".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE...WHEN...ELSE...END`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      t.name AS tname, 
      t.task_group AS tg,
      CASE WHEN tgs.keyid = t.task_group THEN tgs.name ELSE 'something else' END AS tgname
      FROM tasks AS t, task_users AS tu, task_groups AS tgs
      WHERE (tu.worker = 1 AND t.keyid = tu.task);
```